# Data from entity are not showing on page from Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transaction")
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "transaction_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "wallet_name", nullable = false)
    private String walletName;

    @NotNull(message = "Please, insert a amount")
    @Min(value = 0, message = "Please, insert a positive amount")
    private Double amount;

    private String note;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(name = "date")
    private LocalDate date;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "wallet_id", nullable = false)
    private Wallet wallet;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "transaction_type", columnDefinition = "ENUM('EXPENSE', 'INCOME')")
    private TransactionType transactionType;

    @Nullable
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "expense_categories", columnDefinition = "ENUM('FOOD_AND_DRINK', 'SHOPPING', 'TRANSPORT', 'HOME'," +
            " 'BILLS_AND_FEES', 'ENTERTAINMENT', 'CAR', 'TRAVEL', 'FAMILY_AND_PERSONAL', 'HEALTHCARE'," +
            " 'EDUCATION', 'GROCERIES', 'GIFTS', 'BEAUTY', 'WORK', 'SPORTS_AND_HOBBIES', 'OTHER')")
    private ExpenseCategories expenseCategories;

    @Nullable
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "income_categories", columnDefinition = "ENUM('SALARY', 'BUSINESS', 'GIFTS', 'EXTRA_INCOME', 'LOAN', 'PARENTAL_LEAVE', 'INSURANCE_PAYOUT', 'OTHER')")
    private IncomeCategories incomeCategories;
```

Because, I want to display transactions by date on page I created a separated class like this:

```
public class TransactionGroup {
    private LocalDate date;
    private List<Transaction> transactions;
   

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public List<Transaction> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }

    public void setTransactions(List<Transaction> transactions) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }

    public void setTransactions(String walletName, Double amount, String note, LocalDate date, TransactionType transactionType, ExpenseCategories expenseCategories, IncomeCategories incomeCategories) {
    }
}
```

So, as you can see I have a list of transactions. In my controller where I'm saving transaction I have this:

```
@PostMapping("/saveIncome/{walletId}")
public String saveIncome(@PathVariable(value = "walletId") long walletId, @Valid Transaction transaction, BindingResult result, Model model) {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    long userId = user.getId();

    Wallet wallet = walletService.getWalletById(walletId);
    TransactionGroup transactionGroup = new TransactionGroup();

    boolean thereAreErrors = result.hasErrors();
    if (thereAreErrors) {
        model.addAttribute("incomeCategories", IncomeCategories.values());
        return "income_transaction";
    }

    transaction.setWallet(wallet);
    transaction.setUserId(userId);
    transaction.setWalletName(wallet.getWalletName());
    transactionGroup.setTransactions(transaction.getWalletName(), transaction.getAmount(), transaction.getNote(), transaction.getDate(), transaction.getTransactionType(), transaction.getExpenseCategories(), transaction.getIncomeCategories());
    transactionService.saveIncome(transaction, walletId, userId);
    return "redirect:/api/wallet/userWallet/balance/" + userId;
}
```

This is the thing:

```
transactionGroup.setTransactions(transaction.getWalletName(), transaction.getAmount(), transaction.getNote(), transaction.getDate(), transaction.getTransactionType(), transaction.getExpenseCategories(), transaction.getIncomeCategories());
```

And that works fine, transaction is saved. Now when I want to show data from that entity like this:

```
<div th:each="group : ${transactionGroup}">
    <h1 th:text="${group.date}"/>

    <div th:each="transaction : ${group.transactions}">
        <h2>Amount: <span th:text="${transactions.amount}"></span></h2><br>
        <h2>Note: <span th:text="${transactions.note}"></span></h2><br>
        <h2>Wallet name: <span th:text="${transactions.walletName}"></span></h2><br>
        <h2>Expense Category: <span th:text="${transactions.expenseCategories}"></span></h2><br>
        <h2>IncomeCategory: <span th:text="${transactions.incomeCategories}"></span></h2>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting a blank page without any transaction data.

I already asked a question similar to this, you can see it from my profile. Idk what to try more and why data is not displayed so far.

Comment: `public void setTransactions(String walletName, Double amount, String note, LocalDate date, TransactionType transactionType, ExpenseCategories expenseCategories, IncomeCategories incomeCategories) {  }` this method does exactly 1 thing, and that is nothing

Comment: Its supposed to fill transactions list?

Comment: I would think so, but you haven't implemented anything